# JQuery: How to get the element in a class selector based function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("#x1").focus();
$('#x1').get(0).focus();

$('.inputTextBox').focus(function() {
  //This is where I need help... how to get the
  //element of the element that is getting focus?
  var myElement = document.getElementById('x1');
  myElement.style.backgroundColor = "#A7C942";
  myElement.style.color = "black";
  myElement.style.fontSize = "2em";
});

$('inputTextBox').blur(function() {
  //This is where I need help... how to get the
  //element of the element that is losing focus?
  var myElement = document.getElementById('x1');
  myElement.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
  myElement.style.color = "black";
  myElement.style.fontSize = "2em";
});
```

```css
.inputTextBox {
  background: gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div data-role="content">
    <fieldset>
      <label>x1</label>
      <input id="x1" , autofocus="autofocus" , class="inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>x2</label>
      <input id="x2" , class="inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>x3</label>
      <input id="x3" , class="inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" style="width:100%" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The input boxes and the `Ids` will be generated automatically so I need to figure out how to get the element that is firing the `focus` and `blur` events.

Can I pass these somehow?  Or can I get from the DOM?

**NOTE:** I have tried to use the Onfocus and the onblur inside the input tag, but this only works for chrome. I can't get this to work for IE.

Second question:  Is there any way to tab JUST over the control elements?   When I tab past the button I would like to loop back to the first textbox, but instead I hit other elements in the header first.

Comment: Well I am amazed this works anywhere because you haven't referenced the jQuery library you're trying to use... also `$('inputTextBox')` should be `$('.inputTextBox')` you're missing the `.`

Comment: how to get the element of the element that is losing focus? use `$(this)` as an selector

Comment: `var curElement = document.activeElement;` will give you the currently focused element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `jQuery` solution. Since you have `$` selector in your code.

```js
//Jquery Solution
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.inputTextBox').focus(function () {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
  }).blur(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
  });
});
```

```css
.inputTextBox {
    background:gray;
    background-color:gray;
    color:black;
    font-size:2em
    }

.focus{
  background: #A7C942;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div data-role="content">
    <fieldset>
          <label>x1</label>
           <input   id = "x1", autofocus ="autofocus", class = "inputTextBox" />
   </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
       <label>x2</label>
        <input   id = "x2", class = "inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
       <label>x3</label>
       <input   id = "x3", class = "inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>


   <input type="submit" value="Log in" style="width:100%" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you're asking to bing your items.

Select first the `fieldset`, then bind the `input` focus and blur, and applyu css rules to `label`

**edit**

I added the `tab` part to the fiddle.

You need a counter (select) and on each keydown on document, if it's a tab, you can focus the next (or first) input.

Note that when you focus on an input, you need to set the select variable to the current one.

```js
var select = 0;

$('fieldset').each(function(index) {
  var $fieldset = $(this);
  var $input = $fieldset.find('input');
  var $label = $fieldset.find('label');
  $input.focus(function() {
    select = index;
    $label.css({
      backgroundColor: "#A7C942",
      color: "black",
      fontSize: "2em"
    });
  }).blur(function() {
    $label.css({
      backgroundColor: "gray",
      color: "black",
      fontSize: "2em"
    });
  });
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var inputs = $("fieldset input");
  var next = select < (inputs.length - 1) ? select + 1 : 0;
  $("fieldset input")[next].focus();;
})

$("fieldset input")[select].focus();
```

```css
.inputTextBox {
  background: gray;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div data-role="content">
    <fieldset>
      <label>x1</label>
      <input id="x1" , autofocus="autofocus" , class="inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>x2</label>
      <input id="x2" , class="inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>x3</label>
      <input id="x3" , class="inputTextBox" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" style="width:100%" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ... this works ... very nice.   I appreciate that you included code to capture the keypress ... I modified this to only capture the enter key press and this was a nice bonus